List<Map<String, dynamic>> to DropdownMenuItem in Flutter
I have a class FullCurrencyList in a separate file currencies.dart which I try to import on a second page and then build a DropdownMenuItem widget.
Now I am getting the followign error:
The argument type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<FullCurrencyList>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>?'
class FullCurrencyList {
  static final List<Map<String, dynamic>> currencies = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    <String, dynamic>{
      "code": "USD",
      "name": "United States Dollar",
    }
  ];
}

Here is my full code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:brain/util/currencies.dart';

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {

  String? _valCurrency;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _currencyList = FullCurrencyList.currencies;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: Text(("Please, select your currency:"),
          ),
        ),
        new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Text(("Currency") + ":",
              )
            ),
            Container(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10),
                hint: Text("Select"),
                value: _valCurrency,
                items: _currencyList.map<DropdownMenuItem<FullCurrencyList>>((FullCurrencyList value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<FullCurrencyList>(
                    value: value,
                     child: Text(value.name + ' ' + value.code),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? value) {
                  setState(() {
                     _valCurrency = value!;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
        ]),
    ]);
  }
}


Your currency list is not of type FullCurrencyList, it's of type List<Map<String, dynamic>>. Just because you named the class like that doesn't mean that currencies is of that type. I'm assuming you'd like the code to actually be the value, then you can replace your items parameter with this
            items: _currencyList.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((Map<String, dynamic> value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value['code'],
                 child: Text(value['name'] + ' ' + value['code']),
              );
            }).toList(),

